# Надо запустить скрипт после скачивания файла на ПК

Tags: ffmpeg, download, format, webp

Я очень часто скачиваю файлы из интернета для дальнейшей обработки. Но меня сильно бесят файлы с форматом .webp .gif(в случае не анимированного изображения)

Можно ли как-то например автоматически после скачивания запустить .bat скрипт используя например

```
ffmpeg -i "download.webp" "download.png"
```

Ну или есть способ скачивать изображения только в нужном формате?